# is it possible to get activity in TileService?

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to launch a method from the onClick method on TileService , but my method require the activity object , i didn't figure out how to get it on TileService

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class TileService:TileService() {
    val TAG ="Tile"


 
    // Called when the user taps on your tile in an active or inactive state.
    override fun onClick() {
        super.onClick()
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ")
        Toast.makeText(application, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        AppHelper.getInstance().startMethod("Here i need activity object ")

    }
    // Called when the user removes your tile.
    override fun onTileRemoved() {
        super.onTileRemoved()
        Log.d(TAG, "onTileRemoved: ")
    }

}
```

Comment: The answer to the question is No. There is a lot of reasons why. What do you need the activity for?

Comment: I am using Media Projection Api , for exemple the startActivityForResult needs  the activity

Comment: With newer APIs you are not allowed to start activity from background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Im trying to launch a method from the onClick method on TileService , but my method require the activity object , i didn't figure out how to get it on TileService

There may not *be* an `Activity` object. There is no requirement for you to have a running process at the time the user clicks on your tile.

> I am using Media Projection Api , for exemple the startActivityForResult needs the activity

You probably can call `startActivity()` from a tile. So, call `startActivity()` for some activity of yours, and that can call `startActivityForResult()` to start the media projection confirmation dialog.